# How do I get the Ember index.html to appear in dist directory instead of the firebase welcome page?

Tags: ember.js, firebase, ember-cli

First time doing this so I'm not sure what to do.

I initialized firebase, set dist as the public folder, ran `ember build -prod`, then `firebase deploy`.

I see the page welcoming me to firebase hosting, but I'm wondering how I get the index.html from my Ember app to appear instead of the index.html that firebase has added.

Here's my firebase.json file:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The index.html in /dist is firebase hosting and the index.html in /app is the Ember App one.

How do I get my app to appear?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried changing it to `"public": "app"`?

Comment: Just now. It still displays the firebase welcome page. I can navigate to other pages in my app but it just displays some handlebar code. 

Besides, I think ember builds to dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase CLI will deploy whatever files are specified in your `hosting.public` directory from `firebase.json`. In this case, you could run `cat dist/index.html` and you'll likely see the contents of the Firebase Hosting default page.

It sounds like you need to investigate your Ember build process and determine where exactly the output files are going. You can also use `firebase serve` locally to see a preview of what will be deployed without having to actually do a deploy.